# javascript: array.length evaluates as undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

Simple block of code, looping through an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    jsonPost.locationNames.push(locations[i].name);
}
```

Please see the screenshot - this looks to me like a legitimate array, the debugger shows 6 entries and a length of 6.

[debug snapshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2bkq.png)

However, locations.length evaluates to undefined. (See second screen-shot.) I even used the 'copy property path' feature from the debugger to ensure that my code doesn't have a typo but still no joy - locations.length = 6 in the debug window but it evaluates as undefined within my code.

[debug snapshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnB0M.png)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Some respondents have asked for more code. Here is more context:

The method getInsights is called from within the promise function which is the result of an asynchronous $http.get. So yes, the origin of the data is asynchronous however that data is fully resolved by the time it is passed to this method. (Unless I completely misunderstand the mechanics of the promise construct. Which is possible - this environment is very new to me.)

```
try {
      debugAlert("getLocations:Will fetch Locations");
      $http.get("https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/" + acct.name + "/locations" + angularScope.accessToken()).
          then(function (response, acct) {
              angularScope.viewLocations(response.data);
              angularScope.getInsights(response.data);
         });
 }
```

(I doubt you need the full code of the method in which this $http.get/promise is coded and I am initially not including this because I don't want to muddy the waters. If you feel you need it, let me know.)

Here is the complete getInsights method. (Again, it's all fairly straightforward until we get to the json array processing.)

```
$scope.getInsights = function (locations) {

    debugAlert("getInsights:Enter");

    if (!userSignedIn) {
        debugAlert("getInsights:Bail");
        insights = null;
        return;
    }

    debugAlert("getInsights:Initialize insights");
    $scope.insights = "Insights are being initialized...";

    try {
         debugAlert("getInsights:Will fetch Insights");

         var url = "https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/" + $scope.selectedAcct.name + "/locations:reportInsights" + angularScope.accessToken();

         var jsonPost = {
             "locationNames": [],
             "basicRequest": {
                 "metricrequests": [],
                 "timerange": {
                     "startTime": "",
                     "endTime" : ""
                 }
             }
         };

         for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
             jsonPost.locationNames.push(locations[i].name);
         }
         $http.post(url, jsonPost).
            then(function (response) {
                angularScope.viewInsights(response.data);
            });
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("getInsights:Error!");
        alert("getInsights:" + err);
    }
     debugAlert("getInsights:Ready to Exit");
     return function () {
        return fn.apply();
     }
 };
```

This line of code never executes -

```
   jsonPost.locationNames.push(locations[i].name);
```

because the expression locations.length evaluates to undefined which is completely mystifying because the debugger shows very clearly that this property exists and it's value at the time of the break (first breakpoint - second one never hits) is 6.

[image: location.length evaluates to 6 within debugger]

Please see the screen-shots. I'm happy to provide as much code as necessary. At the same time, seeing the debug information adds context and augments the question which I am asking. Thanks!

I threw in the statement

console.log(JSON.stringify(locations));

just prior to the loop. Here is what this yields -

{"locations":[{"name":"accounts/1060596######92928/locations/1520987######801267","locationName":"Lawrence Primus MD","primaryPhone":"(123) 456-7890","primaryCategory":...

Is this the problem? Is locations not actually an array, but rather an object containing an array? If so, how do I reference the array? Thanks!

Comment: please show more code

Comment: unrelated: var names like `jsonPost` hurt your thinking. JSON is always a string, and _never_ anything else. You're clearly dealing with an object; just name it `post`.

Comment: Are you sure that's *actually* the property `length` you are getting from the array? I can see it's not misspelled (usually the mistake is somebody mistyping it "leng**h**t") but you are you using something weird like a Cyrillic **e** there or something? Another question here is - is that a *problem*? Maybe it's shown as `undefined` in the debugger but does the loop even work? If it does, then it might be just a display issue. Or even a hidden feature (I'm only half joking).

Comment: For now, let's assume that `locations` was either defined after this `for` loop or inside of a `function()` that doesn't let `locations` outside its scope. Till you can provide more code, it is hard to say anything else.

Comment: Sorry just saw your first screenshot. But still need more code to figure out the problem. And avoid images of code, rather put the code itself here.

Comment: Which breakpoint were you halting at? The first or the second? (and are both screenshots from the same breakpoint?)

Comment: Whether or not it's relevant in this instance, keep in mind that expanding an array or object in the console will show the values of that object *at the time of expansion*. If you were to create an empty array, log it console, and add 6 items on the next line, expanding the array in the console would show 6 items. Given that your initial log seems to show `Array(6)`, I don't think that's the case, but food for thought.

Comment: @tyler breakpoints halt js execution. There is no way that some values changed in the meantime, as nothing was running ...

Comment: @JonasWilms, to be absolutely sure, could you add the following line just before the loop: `console.log(JSON.stringify(locations));` That should remove most doubts about what exactly you have there.

Comment: @trincot: I threw in the statement 

console.log(JSON.stringify(locations));

just prior to the loop. Here is what this yields -

{"locations":[{"name":"accounts/1060596######92928/locations/1520987######801267","locationName":"Lawrence Primus MD","primaryPhone":"(123) 456-7890","primaryCategory":...

Is this the problem? Is locations not actually an array, but rather an object containing an array? If so, how do I reference the array? Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, that is the issue. So do `locations = locations.locations` before going to the loop.

Comment: @trincot. Thanks! Do you want credit for the answer? If you post it, I'll accept it as the answer. Otherwise, I'll write it in so that other developers can benefit in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Posted. I will also upvote Lenny's answer who posted right after we identified the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases it can help to explicitly stringify the object and output it to the console. As you commented, that outputs:

> {"locations":[{"name":"accounts/1060596######92928/locations/1520987######801267","locationName":"Lawrence Primus MD","primaryPhone":"(123) 456-7890","primaryCategory":...

And so it becomes clear that `locations` is not the array, but the property `locations` is. This can be quite hard to spot in the console, although once you know it, it becomes evident there also.

So to fix, just change the `locations` variable to represent that inner array:

```
locations = locations.locations;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look closely at your debugger (in your last screenshot) you'll see location is not an array it is actually an object with a key `locations` which is an array. That is why locations.length is undefined.

This is the data in the variable locations

```
{
  locations: [
    { name: '...' },
    { name: '...' },
    { name: '...' },
    { name: '...' },
  ]
}
```

So all you need to do is...

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.locations.length; i++) {
```

and it should work.

Alternatively, you can just pass in the locations array when you call the function.

```
angularScope.getInsights(response.data.locations);
```

which is probably cleaner